# "Visitor" instead of "Dish"

Tags: articles, translation, synonyms

I have two small questions. I'm translating a gastronomy website and the original text sometimes refer to the dish as the visitor. For example:

> The next visitor of our table was mackerel with olive and orange oil accompanied by xxx

Does it sound weird? Or what would else would you prefer to use instead of visitor?

Another question: Is it okay to omit "the" before the name of a dish?

Comment: could xxx be 'Sarah'?

Comment: *next arrival at our table ...*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visitor does sound weird to these English ears. Perhaps "arrival" is closer to the intention of the original author? It is commonly used for inanimate objects.

> The next arrival at our table was a dish of mackerel...

Comment: I didn'T know I could use it. It'll diversify my alternatives. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Is the original in English?  If so, yeah, *visitor* sounds weird. (Like the mackerel is still alive.) Use "dish," or "selection," or "presentation," or "plate" ("*at* or, *to* our table," will sound better in most cases than *"of")*. "The" before the dish would be used if it is a house special or if the chef or restaurant is known for it. (Otherwise, you don't need it.)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing weird about it.  "Visitor" is being used in a metaphorical sense to denote the next arriving item in the series of dishes that were sampled.  The dishes were presumably brought to the table individually, as they were sampled.

Yes, you could use "dish" or some other word, but likely this sentence is part of a longer article where "dish", "plate", et al, have already been used, and the author is (quite validly) attempting to avoid repetitiveness.

The only thing I'd change is to say "The next visitor *to* our table was mackerel ..." or, probably better, "The next visitor *at* our table was mackerel ...".